# ASP.NET Core 2.0. Wrong startup file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I had the "index.html" file and it started as a startup file by default with the following code

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(); 
}
```

Then I removed the "index.html" file from my project but it still starts as the startup file even though my code now is

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
    }); 
}
```

I have restarted my Visual Studio and rebuilt the project but this didn't help. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you still have `index.html` in the `wwwroot` folder. Try removing it there first and then restart your application.

Comment: I did these actions. It seems like the app memorize its previous state or something like that.